# IIS Rewrite everything after the domain

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have to domains - a.com and b.com. I want to use iis rewrite so that anything going to www.a.com/ will be redirected to www.b.com/index.asp?i=.

For example www.a.com/XXX will be redirected to www.b.com/index.asp?i=XXX

I put (.*?) in the pattern. The problem is when I enter http://www.b.com/index.asp?i={REQUEST_URI} as a redirect action, the redirect url includes a slash. For example www.a.com/XXX is redirected to www.b.com/index,asp?i=/XXX instead of to i=XXX. Is there any way to get rid of the slash?

Answer (score 0):

You could use below url rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="test1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".+" />
<conditions>
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.b.com/index.asp?i={R:0}" />
```

[image]

Regards,
Jalpa

Comment: did you try that rule? as you can see its work on my side.[image1](https://i.imgur.com/Wd0O1Rw.jpg) and [image2](https://i.imgur.com/GGbKH8l.jpg)as you  can see in image {R:0} contain the url. do you just want to redirect a.com file or also want to redirect a.com to b.com/index.asp?i=  ?